# How to make a div shrink away for 100% to 0%, towards another element on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is a CSS3 transition like described below feasible?

Given a modal overlay, on close, instead of just fading out, I would like to have it scale in size from 100% to 0% towards a specific button on the page.

Has anyone seen this done with CSS3? Possible?

Thanks

Comment: please push your code for better understanding

Comment: Do you know the location of the button? At least relative to your overlay?

Comment: It *should* be possible with the transition property, but I can't make it work with width in Chrome or Firefox. Width is listed as a transitional property by the W3C specs though...

Answer (score 0):

If you know the position of the button you're trying to shrink the overlay toward, you can animate the top, bottom, left, and right of the overlay to the top, bottom, left, and right of the button, respectively. If it varies, you might need some kind of JavaScript hook to determine the position of the button, like using jQuery's `.offset`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?http://jsfiddle.net/AZWhQ/1/

```
.myOverlay{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transition:  -webkit-transform .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:  -moz-transform .5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:  -ms-transform .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition:  -o-transform .5s ease-out;
    transition:  transform .5s ease-out;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.myOverlayClose{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.0);
    -o-transform: scale(0.0);
    transform: scale(0.0);
}
```

[check the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AZWhQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible - here is a very simplistic version of it done by setting the `transform-origin`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/AZWhQ/6/)

Code:

```
document.getElementById('dismiss').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
    var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

    overlay.style['-webkit-transform-origin'] = (button.offsetLeft + button.offsetWidth/2) + 'px ' + 
                                                (button.offsetTop + button.offsetHeight/2) + 'px';

    overlay.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'scale(0)';

    overlay.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
        overlay.className = 'hide';
    });
});
```

The most difficult part of doing this would be to get the buttons position relative to the overlay.  Then use that to set the `transform-origin` which will act as the vanishing point.